# Are members of a C++ struct initialized to 0 by default?

Tags: c++

I have this `struct`:

```
struct Snapshot
{
    double x; 
    int y;
};
```

I want `x` and `y` to be 0. Will they be 0 by default or do I have to do:

```
Snapshot s = {0,0};
```

What are the other ways to zero out the structure?

Comment: Use a std::map<> and return 0 when a key does not exist.

Comment: Note [using indeterminate values is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Answer (score 311, accepted):

They are not null if you don't initialize the struct.

```
Snapshot s; // receives no initialization
Snapshot s = {}; // value initializes all members
```

The second will make all members zero, the first leaves them at unspecified values. Note that it is recursive:

```
struct Parent { Snapshot s; };
Parent p; // receives no initialization
Parent p = {}; // value initializes all members
```

The second will make `p.s.{x,y}` zero. You cannot use these aggregate initializer lists if you've got constructors in your struct. If that is the case, you will have to add proper initalization to those constructors

```
struct Snapshot {
    int x;
    double y;
    Snapshot():x(0),y(0) { }
    // other ctors / functions...
};
```

Will initialize both x and y to 0. Note that you can use `x(), y()` to initialize them disregarding of their type: That's then value initialization, and usually yields a proper initial value (0 for int, 0.0 for double, calling the default constructor for user defined types that have user declared constructors, ...). This is important especially if your struct is a template.

Comment: This produces lots of warnings in my compiler.

Comment: Roger: Try to use the named struct in the initializer, that's what I do and I don't get any warnings in VC 2012: Snapshot s = Snapshot();

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb Will `Snapshot s = {};` work for non POD members (for zeroing them)?

Comment: C++11 now allows you to initialize them in the definition of the struct or class, like so:
    struct Snapshot
        {
            double x{0}; //with braces
            int   y = 0 ; //or just old school style 'by assignement' which is really initialization too
        };

Comment: I noticed that `Snapshot s = {3.0};` seems to initialize s.x to 3.0 and s.y to 0. Is this statement standards conforming or relying on implementation?

Comment: Is "Snapshot s = {};" part of the standard?

Comment: @Stefan See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Comment: I compiled the same code as C and as C++, to check the `mystruct_t s = {}` syntax. It compiled w/o a problem in both languages. But does it initialize the object to 0 in C as well?

Comment: Answering myself: According to this Wikipedia text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)#Initialization , I guess that this applies to C as well, but only for statically allocated objects. Otherwise (i.e., non-static), if at least one member initialiser is given, then the other members are initialized to 0.

Comment: @ysap no,  `= { }` is not valid C. If it is supported somewhere as an extension I believe it would work exactly as if `{ 0 }`

Answer (score 41):

No, they are not 0 by default.  The simplest way to ensure that all values or defaulted to 0 is to define a constructor

```
Snapshot() : x(0), y(0) {
}
```

This ensures that all uses of Snapshot will have initialized values.

Comment: The downside is that the struct is no longer a POD type, because it has a constructor.  That will break some operations such as writing it to a temporary file.

Comment: @finnw: C++11 fixes this, although the struct is not POD, it is "standard layout".

Answer (score 22):

In general, no. However, a struct declared as file-scope or static in a function /will/ be initialized to 0 (just like all other variables of those scopes):

```
int x; // 0
int y = 42; // 42
struct { int a, b; } foo; // 0, 0

void foo() {
  struct { int a, b; } bar; // undefined
  static struct { int c, d; } quux; // 0, 0
}
```

Comment: That's really not a safe assumption. you shouldn't rely on the value of anything you did not initialize

Comment: Static storage duration objects are always initialized to zero - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60653/is-global-memory-initialized-in-c/60707#60707 for a citation from the standard. Whether this is good style is another matter.

Comment: I don't know but I am continuously getting 0's although I didn't initialize them: `struct Point2D {
 int x;
 int y;
};

int main() {
    struct Point2D p2d;
 cout << p2d.x << endl;
 cout << p2d.y << endl;
}`
.I tried compiling and running this code on a loop for a while. Using: `g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`

Answer (score 14):

With POD you can also write

```
Snapshot s = {};
```

You shouldn't use memset in C++, memset has the drawback that if there is a non-POD in the struct it will destroy it.

or like this:

```
struct init
{
  template <typename T>
  operator T * ()
  {
    return new T();
  }
};

Snapshot* s = init();
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh wat?

Comment: @Andy Most Vexing Parse turns things that look like normal ctors -- `SomeType foo();` is the typical one, though it can happen with others -- into function definitions (in that case, a function `foo` that returns `SomeType`). Sorry for the necro, but if anyone else stumbles across this, figured I'd answer.

Answer (score 8):

In C++, use no-argument constructors. In C you can't have constructors, so use either `memset` or - the interesting solution - designated initializers:

```
struct Snapshot s = { .x = 0.0, .y = 0.0 };
```

Comment: I believe this is C, not C++. It will fail to compile under some C++ compilers. I experienced the compile failure under Cygwin or MinGW.

Comment: This will work in C or C++20. In older C++ standards it will only work if your compiler is gracious.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a POD (essentially a C struct) there is little harm in initialising it the C way:

```
Snapshot s;
memset(&s, 0, sizeof (s));
```

or similarly

```
Snapshot *sp = new Snapshot;
memset(sp, 0, sizeof (*sp));
```

I wouldn't go so far as to use `calloc()` in a C++ program though.

Comment: Same holds for double; all-bits-zero isn't necessarily 0.0 . However, you can check if you have IEEE754 doubles, in which case it must work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct answer is that their values are undefined.  Often, they are initialized to 0 when running debug versions of the code.  This is usually not the case when running release versions.

Comment: Actually the debug versions just happen to already have `0` in those places in memory. This is not the same as initialisation!

Answer (score 1):

Move pod members to a base class to shorten your initializer list:

```
struct foo_pod
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct foo : foo_pod
{
    std::string name;
    foo(std::string name)
        : foo_pod()
        , name(name)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f("bar");
    printf("%d %d %d %s\n", f.x, f.y, f.z, f.name.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is super old, but this question popped up for me on google and I found this other way and figured I'd add it here:

```cpp
Snapshot s {};
```

I'm not sure what C/C++ language version you need for this syntax.

Comment: This is probably the best answer for C++11 and newer. I believe it's a special case of _aggregate initialization_? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization