# How to zero-initialize an union?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
struct T {
    int a;
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
        } s1;
        struct {
            char b[1024];
        } s2;
    };
};

int main() {
    T x = T();
}
```

Since an explicit constructor is called, the above code ends-up zero-initializing all the data members in x.

But I would like to have x zero-initialized even if an explicit is not called. To do that one idea would be to initialize the data members in their declaration, which seems to be okay for T::a. But how can I zero-initialize all the memory occupied by the union by using
the same criteria?

```
struct T {
    int a = 0;
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
        } s1;
        struct {
            char b[1024];
        } s2;
    };
};

int main() {
    T x; // I want x to be zero-initialized
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a union without a user-defined default constructor, *value initialization* is *zero initialization*.

However, zero-initialization of a union may not zero all memory, but only the padding and the first member.  If the first member isn't the largest, you could be left with non-zero content.

Since you know that `s2` is largest, you can make a default constructor that zeros it:

```
struct T
{
    int a;
    union {
        int s1a;
        char s2b[1024];
    };
    T() : a(), s2b() {}
};
```

And now

```
T x;
```

will be zeroed.

Comment: @Martin: No, it's not.  But it is "standard layout".

Comment: Doesn't just adding '{}' to struct { char b[1024];} s2 = {}; solve my problem with union? In this case int main() { T x; } calls all the default-initializers, when the union is met, the following from the standard apply: "— if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the
initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor)" (see 8.5.1)

Comment: @Martin: Yes.  Do note this sentence in section 9.5p2 "At most one non-static data member of a union may have a *brace-or-equal-initializer*."

Comment: Perhaps the Standard intents that the entire union object is filled with zero. The Standard says "the object's first non-static named data member is zero initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;". With respect to an union's active object, the memory that follows it until the end of the union *is* actually padding I believe - reserved for when the union represents an object of its other member types. Note that there may not be any padding before the active object in an union.

Comment: @litb: You need some sort of reference to back up that interpretation of "padding bits", since "bits that are not part of the storage for *any* member" is also a viable definition, and it isn't by any means impossible for a union to contain bits that don't overlap any member, for alignment reasons.

Answer (score 11):

You could zeroize using `memset`:

```
memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));
```

Comment: It's not unreasonable to use memset in C++. I think there's an iterator in <memory> that can be used with std::fill somehow to get the same effect, but memset is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to implement a constructor for `T`:

```
struct T {
    int a;
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
        } s1;
        struct {
            char b[1024];
        } s2;
    };
    T() : a(), s2() {} // <- proper initialisation
};
```

In this case, I picked the largest member of your `union` since it's transparent. Otherwise you could explicitly create the `union` itself.