# Different results calculating the average of double variables contained in a vector of structs by altering code formatting?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am currently fighting with a very odd behavior of OpenCV/C++. This is what i am doing:

Updated 1:  Here more informations:

I calculate the gradient orientation for a set of pixels and store them in a `double` field of a self declared `struct`. The struct elements get stored in a vector.

```
myfunct1() {
    (...)
    c.grad_orientation = (sum_ori / highgrads.size()) + M_PI; // +M_PI because i just  want to rotate the angle around 180°.
    (...)
    my_struct_vector.push_back(c);
}
```

I later got several `c` stored in a vector and want to estimate the average of every single `grad_orientation`, stored in every struct-element of my vector looking like this:

```
myfunct0() {
    myfunct1(); //adds element to the my_struct_vector
    (...)
    int n = 0;
    double total_ori = 0.0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < my_struct_vector.size(); ++i) {
        total_ori += my_struct_vector[i].grad_orientation;
        n++;
    }

    azimuth = (total_ori / n);
    cout << "Average: " << azimuth * 180/M_PI << endl; // print out in degrees
}
```

Now for the funny part: If i do this under certain circumstances, the `cout` prints `215.963`. This is the result i got most often (EXACTLY this result).
In some cases, if i add these matrices named above or (yes, really) if i move the double field holding the `grad_orientation` in the struct one column higher in terms of code i get `223.442`. So the difference between the two results in the code is *only* the following:

```
struct my_struct {

std::vector<cv::Point> contour_shadow;
std::vector<cv::Point> contour_light;
cv::RotatedRect rect;
cv::Point pf; 
cv::Point pc;
double grad_orientation; // this line moved one column down, beneath "grad_flag" results in a differing result.
bool grad_flag;
double grad_magnitude;
```

};

The printed results do not only depend on the position of the column in the struct declaration but also when i alter different parts of my code.

This may has something to do with double precision, but why does it alter if i move columns of code?

Comment: Sounds like some buffer overrunning. Hard to tell without seeing the code that declares your image variables, and the operations performed on them between their instantiation and the function calls above.

Comment: examine how you do the loop. the finishing criteria is craters.size(), but then my_struct[i] ?? I would expect craters[i] instead. Another tip is to use a good debugger, you will find the problem in no time

Comment: on another note, your "edit" seems totally unrelated to your first problem and doesnt seem to have anything to do with opencv. probably out of array bounds or similar

Comment: okay, yeah i am very confused right now. i have deleted obsolte parts to clarify the problem, i hope it's better now. to your first comment: i made a mistake copying the code in here. now it should be clear, sorry. debugging is my last step due to size and complexity of the programm but i will go for it now. thanks.

Comment: if you replace the rows, and happen to use uninitalized memory (which i still believe is the case), then when it try to read grad_orientation it will read it from another part of your (unitialized) memory, because a struct is laid out sequentially in memory defiend by the order of the members. Proably the data at this location is not exactly random, hence the same results every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to Rolle for helping me out on this. I hope it's okay to answer my own question just to mark it answered?
The problem was indeed using uninitialized memory and a bool flag (in the aftermath a wrong decision) inside the struct (what isn't, of course, zero if uninitialized). Things that are quite obvious, but the fact that exchange of rows in the code (even outside the struct!) led to wrong (but somehow non-random) values left me kind of confused.

See here [Are members of a C++ struct initialized to 0 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default)