# Python sentinel in C++ extension

Tags: python, c++, sentinel

I'm working on a Python extension module written in C++.

According to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) the module method table should be written like this:

```
static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    ...
    {"system",  spam_system, METH_VARARGS,
    "Execute a shell command."},
    ...
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};
```

But I see that some developers write the sentinel like this:

```
static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    ...
    {"system",  spam_system, METH_VARARGS,
    "Execute a shell command."},
    ...
    {}                          /* Sentinel */
};
```

My question is the following is there a risk to use the shortened version?

Comment: There does not appear to be any risk.

Comment: According to this post, there is no risk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default

Everything gets initialised to zero by default.

Comment: [psmears](http://stackoverflow.com/users/333698/psmears) made a very interesting point about there not being a problem even if such code is compiled under C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pod class initialized with `{}` has fields not explicitly set zeroed.

If `PyMethodDef` is pod (plain old data), as I suspect, `{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}` will generate the same data as `{}`.

This is true in both C and C++.

If the class `PyMethodDef` was a non-pod class in C++11, `{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}` could do something different than `{}`, but I strongly doubt that is the case here.

The only concern I would have is if the library changed on me to make `PyMethodDef` a non-pod, and chose to make `{}` not zero the data at the same time.  I would find that unlikely.