# Why does PyMethodDef arrays require a sentinel element containing multiple NULLs?

Tags: python, python-c-api

Several Python structures seem to need a sentinel (probably in order to know when to "stop"). But why do some, like arrays of `PyMethodDef`, have a sentinel element initialized with multiple `NULL`s?

For example [`zip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2560):

```c
static PyMethodDef zip_methods[] = {
    {"__reduce__",   (PyCFunction)zip_reduce,   METH_NOARGS, reduce_doc},
    {NULL,           NULL}           /* sentinel */
};
```

Why does the last `PyMethodDef` in the "sentinel array" have the two `NULL`s? Why not just 1? Or given that `__reduce__` has 4 entries why not 4 `NULL`s as sentinel element?

Comment: @Olaf Why remove the C tag? It's C code I'm investigating here after all.

Comment: "_I realize that c needs a sentinel to know when it has to "stop"_" - That's wrong and no requirement of the language, nor used for most arrays in C.

Comment: No, you are investigating a Python implementation with a wrong prerequisite.

Comment: C'mon @Olaf, this is about defining and initialising a C-array. I agree that the title not explicitly tells this, but still ...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the C language, but the Python framework for modules. And there is no `NULL` in the array.

Comment: @Olaf question is about _CPython_ implementation, which **is** implemented in C... While post introduction may contain some invalid presumptions, actual _question_ asked does not deserve such reaction (IMHO).

Comment: @Olaf I may be mistaken but `static PyMethodDef zip_methods[]` creates a C array of `PyMethodDef` structs and the last one (sentinel) contains two NULLs. I think this has more to do with `C` or the `python-C-API` than with python itself, right? However I tried to re-formulate the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @MSeifert: (Ok, I'm fine with the `python-c-api` tag.) Yes, but the `NULL`s are not elements of the array, but of an _element of the array_ (very important difference). So, there are no "multiple terminators" (as they are typically called). Why both fields must be `NULL` (and why no designated initialisers are used) depends on how they ae processed. Reading the Python source code would be a good start.

Comment: @Olaf "Why both fields must be NULL (and why no designated initialisers are used) depends on how they ae processed. Reading the Python source code would be a good start." - That's not really helpful. If I knew what and where to look for in the source code I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: It is the best advice, given your question does not show any effort on your own. What is the problem? The CPython sources are free and easily grep-able. OTOH, you could just keep the pattern; it is not clear what your problem is anyway, von mir aus omit the second null pointer constant; that will not change anything.

Comment: The question is more aimed to understand the pattern that seems to be reused everywhere. If you have a suggestion what to `grep` for that would definetly help.

Comment: There's a least [one example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/65c5b096ac2c6608d296f1603cd4792086108c95/Python/import.c#L3368) of a single-element sentinel in Python 2.7 (gone in 3.x). The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function)  ([Py3](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function)) want you to use `{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}`, which happens basically nowhere. Of course: [`{}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359255/python-sentinel-in-c-extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it does. For two reasons:

1) In the Python source code it only checks the name against NULL.

As far as I'm aware, `PyMethodDef` arrays are used in two places: when attaching methods to a type, and when attaching methods to a module.

To find the relevant bit of code start by noting that all types go through `PyType_Ready` and most modules go through `PyModule_Init` so start the search there. `PyModule_Create` forwards to `PyModule_Create2`. In `PyType_Ready` the methods get dealt with by the internal function [`add_methods`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e1ddbd592c3aaf02a58789771f891c0101c6e05/Objects/typeobject.c#L5071). In `PyModule_Create2` there is all call to [`PyModule_AddFunctions`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18b250f844bf8b2d1a81c2d2dcc74e850364fe35/Objects/moduleobject.c#L211) which is actually a [public function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_AddFunctions) if you want to do low level stuff yourself and which in turn calls the internal function `_add_methods_to_object`.

Both of these internal functions have a for loop to loop over the methods and add them to the relevant dictionary. In [both](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18b250f844bf8b2d1a81c2d2dcc74e850364fe35/Objects/moduleobject.c#L139) [cases](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e1ddbd592c3aaf02a58789771f891c0101c6e05/Objects/typeobject.c#L4654) the condition to continue looping is `meth->ml_name!=NULL`.

Therefore, at least currently, only the name is checked.

2) [In both C and C++ partial initialization guarantees that the remaining fields are zero/default initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure). Therefore just initializing the first element of the sentinel to 0 ensures that all the other elements are initialized to 0. You can even just use `{}`.

(As a side note, Python uses this automatic zero initialization a lot with the large structs it defines, for example [`PyTypeObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html) which is huge and which you rarely bother filling in completely.)

After writing this answer I found that this had [already been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359255/python-sentinel-in-c-extension).

---

So in summary - Python only checks the `ml_name` (although that's an implementation detail so I guess could change in future if they find a use for a `NULL` name with a non-`NULL` method), and C automatically zeros the sentinel anyway. I don't know why the convention appears to be to set two elements, but there's something to be said from following convention.