# Value of primitive member in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){
        std::cout << bar_;
    }

private:
    int bar_;
};
```

Is this guaranteed to always output `0`?

In other words - is an `int` member always initialized to `0` before the constructor is executed, if no initializer list is used?

I'm asking because I'm getting a weird error in a project I'm working on, where a private `int` member has the value 32767 at the beginning of a constructor under certain circumstances (which involves too much code and dependencies to post here).

Comment: No it's not initialized to 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default