# Brace-or-equal-initializers in anonymous struct does not work on VS2013

Tags: c++11, member-initialization, visual-c++-2013, anonymous-struct

Brace-or-equal-initializers in an anonymous struct within a struct doesn't do their work on output produced by VS2013. There's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>


struct S
{
    struct
    {
        uint64_t val = 0;
    }anon;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    S *a = new S;

    std::cout << s.anon.val << std::endl;
    std::cout << a->anon.val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with this command on Linux:

```
g++ -std=c++11 def-init-anon-atruct.cpp -o def-init-anon-atruct
```

(Adding optimisation flags does not affect the result)

Expected result:

```
0
0
```

Weird. Running that with VS2013 gives garbage values. Who's right on this one in terms of implementing C++11 standards right? I highly doubt this is GCC's fault.

Is it something to do with some useless VS compiler options? Windows extensions? I have to make default constructors for the structures because of a bug MS made? this is absurd.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default

Comment: I also highly doubt this is gcc's fault.

Comment: Intel's compiler offers better language conformance on Microsoft target platforms.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 (Compiler v141) gives the expected result: http://i.imgur.com/PcddbQ2.png

Comment: What's VS2013's output if you add `anon = {};`?

Comment: @Mine That's not the point here. If I wanted to initialise the structure with additional codes outside the structure, I wouldn't be posting this.

Comment: That's to also @Ben. I don't think many people here actually read questions before they write anything.

Comment: Support ended. No bug to file. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14086/products-reaching-end-of-support-in-the-second-half-of-2016

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 gives the expected result too.

Comment: Good argument for your boss to get a new compiler ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-static data member initialisers being silently ignored in nested anonymous structs is a [confirmed bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808506) in Visual C++ 2013, [fixed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/01/c-compiler-front-end-fixes-in-vs2015/) in Visual C++ 2015 RTM.

Answer (score 6):

> I have to make default constructors for the structures because of a bug MS made? this is absurd.

Yes, and no, it is not absurd.

Compilers are programs too, and tend to have bugs -- some more than others.

If you don't have a choice about the tool, you have to work with the limitations of the tool, no matter how absurd it sounds in theory.