# Segmentation fault while accessing textBox from callback

Tags: c++, qt

I have simple callback functions that provides data to be shown on QT widget main form. As soon breakpoint reaches setText() I have exception `Segmentation fault`:

```
void MainWindow::SetAmount(int value)
{
    ui->tbAmount->setText( QString::number(value) );

}
```

[image]

Why I'm geting souch error? When I call `SetAmount()` from button click it runs fine.

Comment: maybe tbAmount is a nullptr? try adding `if (!(ui->tbAmount)) qDebug() << "null";` and see if it prints

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, you're likely attempting to dereference a `null` pointer.  I would add the following error checking to the method to see if this is the case

```
if (ui == null || ui->tbAmount == null) {
    qDebug() << "NULL Pointer";
}
```

If either `ui` or `ui->tbAmount` is indeed `null`, I would ensure that they are getting properly initialized elsewhere in your implementation before `MainWindow::SetAmount(int value)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the callback from the wrong thread, most likely. It's also possible that you're trying to access it before the object was created (or after it was destructed). Modify as follows:

1. [Value-initialize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069634/1329652) `ui`, in spite of whatever you do in the constructor. Hold it by value. Finally - null the `ui` in the destructor, as a debug aid.
2. Add checks to the callback.

```
#if !defined(DEBUG_INIT) && defined(QT_NO_DEBUG)
#define DEBUG_INIT
#elif !defined(DEBUG_INIT) && !defined(QT_NO_DEBUG)
#define DEBUG_INIT = {}
#endif

class MainWindow : public ... {
  Q_OBJECT
  Ui::MainWindow ui DEBUG_INIT; // held by value
  ...
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = {});
  ~MainWindow() override;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : baseclass(parent) {
  ui.setupUi(this);
  ...
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  ...
  Q_UNUSED((ui DEBUG_INIT));
}

void MainWindow::SetAmount(int value) {
  Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == thread());
  Q_ASSERT(!d_ptr->wasDeleted);
  ui->tbAmount->setText(QString::number(value));
}
```