# initializing struct with {0}

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm debugging some code that essentially is identical to this:

```cpp
struct Foo { int a; int b; };
struct Bar { Bar() {} Foo foo{0}; };
```

When I make an instance of `Bar`, it seems like both `a` and `b` are initialized to zero. Is this guaranteed? Where can I find that in the spec?

Comment: try: `struct Foo { int a{}; int b{}; };` mind the extra braces after the variable names. then you will always get initialized values. if you need to init with other values, with defined behavior, you need to write a ctor like for a every other class

Comment: @skratchi.at Those are not parentheses (using parentheses would mean something else)

Comment: Such a simple question on the surface, but C++ init is so complicated that I understand why you're asking it. I could hazard a guess that you're getting proper aggregate init here _but_ without delving into the standard I am not sure what the answer is. How sad is that?

Comment: This is for arrays, but... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default

Comment: @YSC The question leaves C/C++ open as well... But the accepted answer would definitely apply to this question, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @eike That's true. And this is what matters. The help text of a question closed as duplicate is something in the line of "this question have already been answered here". It doesn't matter if the question is not exactly the same; what matters is that OP can find an answer to their question by following the link.

Comment: @YSC In that case, this should probably be closed as duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members [and bases (since C++17)] or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members [and bases (since C++17)] are initialized [by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)] by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

`Foo` has no default member initializers (`int b{0};`), so `b` will be initialized by list-initialization with an empty list, which means value-initialization for non-class types: `b = int() // = 0`.