# Is a C-struct zero-initialized empty braces in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, language-lawyer, zero-initialization

If with C++17 I do a

```
struct tm mytm{};
int i{};
```

Will the variable `mytm` (and to be on the safe side, also `i`) be zero-initialized?

I am sent in circles through these pages:

- [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization),
- [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization),
- [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) and/or
- [aggregate-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

And the closest thing I can find is from *zero-initialization*:

> ..., including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided

The alternative (I somehow feel right about) would be default-initialization, which would mean no-initialization. But I [find this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default), value-initialization, meaning zeros. Confused...

(I note, that by the [C struct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) the initializer can not be empty. So the argument "like in C" does not hold here.)

Comment: What is a "C struct"?

Comment: @NicolBolas I called a C struct something that would work in C, like "struct tm" from my question. This from the C++ point of view would be a struct with no private data members and no virtual functions. You closed the question with a reference *how* to initialize something to 0, namely with `{0}`, which was not my question. The answer you gave there -- so you say `struct tm mytm{}` is value-initialization. Right? Which in this case... is zero-initialized by "when a named variable (automatic...) is declared with the initializer consisting of a pair of braces." Correct?

Comment: "*which was not my question.*" It was for all useful purposes. It would be answered by any answer to that question (ie: you can't in general, even for your "C structs", and your question still lacks a firm definition for this concept).