# Issue with structures in C language

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have an issue with structures in C, I don't know exactly what is happening. Could you explain me where I am wrong and correct me?

I declared a structure like below

```
typedef struct  
{
    Fuel_Intrl_IDs Curr_Bar;     /*enum variable*/
    uint16_t Pres_Value; 
    uint16_t Prev_Value;
}Bar_Dync_Data;
```

I assigned values for all the 3 variables, then when I am accessing data in these variables, value in "Prev_value is always returning "0".

On reassigning the structure as follows, everything is working fine:

```
typedef struct  
{
    uint16_t Pres_Value; 
    Fuel_Intrl_IDs Curr_Bar;     /*enum variable*/
    uint16_t Prev_Value;
}Bar_Dync_Data;
```

Can you explain what is happening here?

Code for reproducing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint-gcc.h>

typedef enum                                                            /*Fuel Internal IDs*/
{
   Fuel_Intrl_ID_End
}Fuel_Intrl_IDs;

typedef struct                                                          /*Structure for Storing BAR ON/OFF Values*/
{
    Fuel_Intrl_IDs Curr_Bar;
    uint16_t Pres_Value;
    uint16_t Prev_Value;
}Bar_Dync_Data;

 Bar_Dync_Data FBar_Dync_Data;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    FBar_Dync_Data.Prev_Value = 255;
        while(1)
    {
        printf("\n Enter Pres value ");
        scanf("%d",&FBar_Dync_Data.Pres_Value);
        printf("\n Present value:  %d",FBar_Dync_Data.Pres_Value);
        printf("\n Previous value:  %d",FBar_Dync_Data.Prev_Value);
        FBar_Dync_Data.Prev_Value = FBar_Dync_Data.Pres_Value;
       // getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not related to the question itself but `Prev_Value` and `Pres_Value` are not easy to distinguish, what about `current` and `previous` ? not sure `_Value` is bringing a lot

Comment: Most likely you have a buffer overflow in some code unrelated to the structures.

Comment: The `%d` specifier in `scanf` is for the `int` type. You use it on an `uint16_t` which results in undefined behaviour

Comment: Once code attempts to execute the `scanf` my system traps a non-fatal run-time error:   _"Parameter type mismatch; expecting pointer to int but found pointer to short"_.  And, as noted, behavior beyond that point is undefined.  Anything can happen.  Either change type of member `Pres_Value` to `int`, or use the `hu` format specifier in the `scanf` call.

Comment: Also, upon first use of  `Prev_Value` it has not yet been initialized.  Suggest initializing `struct` before using:  `Bar_Dync_Data FBar_Dync_Data = {0};`.  ([more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069621/are-members-of-a-c-struct-initialized-to-0-by-default))

Comment: If you have not yet encountered it in your studies, read about [undefined behavior (UB) here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  As to the different behavior you are observing upon changing member order within struct, it could result from the combined effects of UB and [struct padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing),  Arranged one way, there may appear to be no impact from memory violations, but arranged another way the violation presents itself, as (in my case) a non-fatal run-time error.