# why global variable in C takes zero as initial value?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static variable initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831290/static-variable-initialization)

why global variable in C takes zero as initial value?

Comment: Dupe oof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831290/static-variable-initialization

Comment: What would you prefer?  0xFEEDBEEF?

Comment: @Paul: I'm more 0x0BADF00D kind of guy.

Comment: They don't have to. You can initialize them to any "constant" value (for a peculiar value of "constant"); zero just happens to be the default.

Comment: You can initialize a static variable to something other than zero in the declaration if you wish.

Comment: My new favorite is 0xDECAFBAD.

Answer (score 0):

This required for a compiler to conform to the C standard.

The reason for the design choice is likely that having random garbage in your uninitialized variables makes errors much harder to detect.