# Not able to understand Obfuscated C code

Tags: c

I am not able to understand this. Please explain.

**Edit**: It prints: `'hello, world!'`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
main()
{
  for(;i["]<i;++i){--i;}"];read('-'-'-',i+++"hell\o, world!\n",'/'/'/'));
  //For loop executes once, calling function read with three arguments.
}

read(j,i,p)
{
  write(j/p+p,i---j,i/i);  //how does it work? like printf?
}
```

Comment: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write

Comment: This code invokes undefined behavior for sure.

Comment: In addition to my answer below, see http://codepad.org/lUxvbKZs — on that compiler the program produces no output. Your code is compiler dependant.

Comment: [link](https://ideone.com/KseqFl)   works here

Comment: @haccks and whoever upvoted him, where exactly is the UB?

Comment: OP, C++ is _not_ a superset of C. Some C code--such as this--is _not_ valid C++ --> removed C++ tag.

Comment: @SchighSchagh; I edited my answer. Read it for the explanation "why it is invoking undefined behavior?".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Breaking is down you have:

```
for({initial expr};{conditional expr};{increment expr})
```

The '{initial expr}' is blank so it does nothing.
The '{conditional expr}' is `'i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]'`

which is the same as

```
"]<i;++i){--i;}"[i]
```

or

```
const char* str = "]<i;++i){--i;}";
for (; str[i]; )
```

so it's looping until the expression is false (i.e. is hits the null at the end of the string).

The `{increment expr}` is

```
read('-'-'-',i+++"hell\o, world!\n",'/'/'/')
```

If you break that down the read parameters you have:

```
'-' - '-' == char('-') - char('-') == 0
```

For parameter two you have:

```
i+++"hell\o, world!\n"
```

which is the same as:
    i++ + "hell\o, world!\n"

So it increments the 'i' variable, this means the for loop will loop for the number of characters in conditional string "]

For the first time around you end up with:

> ```
> 0 + "hell\o, world!\n"
> ```

The second time around the loop will be 1 + "hell\o, world!\n", etc.

So the second parameter is a pointer into the "hell\o, world!\n".

The third parameter is:

```
'/'/'/' == '/' / '/' == char('/') / char('/') == 1
```

So the third parameter is always 1.

Now we break down the read function that calls write:

```
write(j/p+p,i---j,i/i);
```

There are three parameters, the first is:

> ```
> j/p+p where j == 0, p == 1 so 0/1+1 == 1.
> ```

If read the link to the write function 1 is hardcoded to write to standard out.

The second parameter to write is

```
i---j
```

which is the same is `i-- - j`, where i is the pointer to the string and `j = 0`, since i is post-decremented is doesn't do anything and `'- 0'` does nothing, it's simply passing the pointer through to the write function.

The third parameter is `'i / i`' which will always be `1`.

So for each call to 'read' it writes one character out of the "hell\o, world!\n" string each time.

Comment: ... except that `i` (the global) starts with an undefined value, so what it actually does is randomly access memory.

Comment: 'i' is defined in the 'global' area so it will always start off being zero. see [static variable initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831290/static-variable-initialization)

Comment: Can you finger-on-paper the spec? Logic and secondary evidence shows I'm wrong but can you finish that thought? E.g. in the C99 spec at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf ?

Comment: Why is `\o` inside `"hell\o, world!"` printed as simple `o`? I could not find that escape sequence.

Comment: Undefined escape codes are taken by most compilers just to be the character. It's a misdirect. E.g. Microsoft mentions it as a 'Microsoft Specific' in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: @halex: actually, I think that in the original version the line was split in two and that backslash was used as a line continuation character. It works anyhow because unknown escape sequences are usually treated as the character itself (probably not standard, but it's widespread behavior).

Answer (score 0):

```
read('-'-'-',i+++"hell\o, world!\n",'/'/'/')
```

Calls `read` with the first argument:

```
'-' - '-'
```

So that's the subtraction of a char from itself, i.e. zero.

The second argument is:

```
i++ + "hell\o, world!\n"
```

So that is an address within the string constant `"hell\o world!\n"` which will depend on the value of `i`.

The third argument is:

```
'/' / '/'
```

A reprise of the arithmetic on character liberals theme, this time producing `1`.

Rather than the normal `read`, that call goes to the method defined at the bottom, which actually performs a `write`.

Argument 1 to the write is:

```
j/p+p
```

Which is 0/1+1 = 1.

Argument 2 is:

```
i-- - j
```

Which undoes the transformation on the earlier string literal, evaluating back to the string `"hell\o world..."`.

The third argument is:

```
i/i
```

i.e. 1.

So the net effect of the read is to write one byte from the string passed in to file descriptor 1.

It doesn't return anything, though it should, so the result and therefore the exact behaviour of the earlier loop is undefined.

The subscript on `i` in the for loop is identical to writing:

```
*((i) + (the string given))
```

i.e. it grabs a byte from within that string. As the initial value of `i` is undefined, this could be an out-of-bounds access.

Note that the `i` within `read` is local, not the global. So the global one continues to increment, passing along one character at a time, until it gets to a terminating null in the other string literal.

If `i` were given 0 as an initial value then this code would be correct.

(EDIT: as has been pointed out elsewhere, I was wrong here: `i` is initially zero because it's a global. Teleologically, it costs nothing at runtime to give globals defined initial values so C does. It would cost to give anything on the stack an initial value, so C doesn't.)

Comment: What you explained is not so obfuscated. The only messing part is `i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]`. what about this?

Comment: @tesseract Wouldn't the rightmost square bracket (for(;i["]<i;++i){--i;}"**]**) be unmatched, then?

Comment: @computerfreaker Look at it this way: `i["..."]` No, the last right square bracket wouldn't be unmatched, the inside right square bracket is a literal.

Comment: @ciphermagi The comment I was replying to had interpreted the sequence as `i[34]<i;++i){--i;}` since " is 34 in decimal, which confused me since the rightmost square bracket would be unmatched at that point.

Comment: @computerfreaker He must have deleted the comment, then.

Comment: yes I just realised that soon as I posted it, deleted my comment. sorry.

Comment: @ciphermagi Yes. @haccks I almost think it's doing a weird iteration through a character array. `for(;` means "start a for loop with no initial value." `i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]` sets up a character array of the same length as the "hello world" string. `;read(` calls the read function on every iteration of the loop; `i` is incremented within the `read` call as opposed to the usual incrementation you'd find in a for loop. So if I'm correct this code runs until `i` reaches the end of its character array. The fact that the character array looks like valid code is probably meant to cause confusion.

Comment: `"string"[i]` and `i["string"]` are the same in C due to the way that square brackets are defined just as a shorthand for addition and dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

First see the syntax of `read` and `write` function in C and what they do:

```
ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

*The `read()` function shall attempt to read `nbyte` bytes from the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`, into the buffer pointed to by `buf`.*

```
ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

*The `write()` function shall attempt to write `nbyte` bytes from the buffer pointed to by `buf` to the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`.*

Now, rewriting your `for` loop as

```
for(;i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]; read('-' - '-', i++ + "hell\o, world!\n", '/' / '/'));
```

Starting with `i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]`;

`"]<i;++i){--i;}"` is a string. In C, if

```
char ch;
char *a = "string";`
```

then you can write `ch = "string"[i]` which is equivalent to `i["string"]` (as `a[i] = i[a]`). This basically add the address of the `string` to `i` (`i` is initialized to `0` as it is globally defined). So, the `i` is initialized with the starting address of string `hell\o, world!\n`.
Now the point is that the `for` loop is not iterating only once!
The expression `read('-' - '-', i++ + "hell\o, world!\n", '/' / '/')` can be rewritten as (for the sake of convenience);

```
read(0, i++ + "hell\o, world!\n", 1)  
                                  ^ read only one byte (one character)
```

Now what it will do actually is to call `read` and increment `i` (using its previous value). Starting address of string `hell\o, world!` get added to `i`. So the first call of read will just print `H`. On next iteration the `i` is incremented (contains the address of next character) and call to read will print the next character.
This will continue until  `i["]<i;++i){--i;}"]` becomes  `false` (at `\0`).

Overall the behavior of code is **undefined**!

---

EXPLANATION for UB:

Note that a function call `f(a,b,c)` is not a use of the *comma operator* and the order of evaluation for `a`, `b`, and `c` is **unspecified**.

Also C99 states that:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, **the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored**.

Hence the call

```
write(j/p+p, i-- -j, i/i);
```

invokes UB. You can't modify and use a variable in the same expression. The compiler should raise a warning

[Warning] operation on 'i' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]