# C++ Scoreboard hard time

Tags: c++, sorting

Hello once again stackoverflow folks, this is really hard and it's been torturing my brain. What I must do is, a multiplayer server-sided scoreboard. Basically 10 clients are connected into my server application, during this event everytime a player kill another player his kills are increased, each player connected to the server have a class pointer

```
class CUser
{
(...)
    public:
    unsigned m_uEventKills;
    unsigned m_uEventDeaths;
(...)
};
```

m_uEvenKills is increased everytime someone kills someone and ofc, m_uEventDeaths also increase for the dying player. Imagine player a,b,c,d,e,f each one of them have random kills (a,b,c,d... is a pointer to CUser) so:

```
a->m_uEventKills is 72
b->m_uEventKills is 13
c->m_uEventKills is 2
d->m_uEventKills is 44
e->m_uEventKills is 21
f->m_uEventKills is 33
```

and random values for deaths.

I have this:

```
int nMax[10];

void OrganizeMax()
{
    memset( &nMax, 0, sizeof( nMax ));
    (...)
```

Organize max must fill nMax, from 0 to 9 (10 top users) reading from all connected users (all of them own a pointer to CUser) ->m_uEventKills, and set to nMax[0] the one with most kills, to nMax[1] the second with most kills, to nMax[2] the thirt with most kills and so on...
Any briliant ideas of how to do this?

-Edit

I'll be more simple, i have 10 vars.

```
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;
a = 3;
b = 61;
c = 29;
d = 44;
e = 12;
f = 8;
g = 27;
h = 11;
i = 0;
j = 4;
```

I need to insert these vars into

```
int nHold[10];
```

in decreasing order, how do I do that?

Comment: then shouldn't nMax be of type CUser * ?

Comment: As an "FYI"...there is no need to `memset` global arrays to zero in C++.  It's in the standard that the compiler will [do this for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991409/how-can-i-initialize-an-array-globally-in-c-or-c).  Moreover, if you ever see things like memset, memcpy, strcat, or the like...then you're not doing things "the C++ way".

Comment: memset is set to 0 because OrganizeMax is called multiple times, so when the array is filled, its set to 0 again OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `a`, `b` ...`f`, I'd use a `std::vector` of `CUser` (BTW, I don't like `CUser` as a class name):

```
std::vector<CUser> users;
```

If this is the *only* order you care about with respect to users, I'd define the ordering as part of the `CUser` class:

```
class CUser { 

    // ...
    bool operator<(CUser const &other) const { 
         return m_uEventKills < other.m_uEventKills;
    }
};
```

Then when you need the users sorted into the correct order, you can do:

```
std::sort(users.begin(), users.end());
```

You will, however, probably need to add an ID number (or something like that) to the `CUser` class to keep track of which user is which, regardless of the order in which they happen to be arranged at the moment.

Edit:

To just get the values of `int`s in a...j into `nHold` in ascending order, you probably want to just insert them in their existing order, then sort:

```
nHold[0] = a;
nHold[1] = b;
//...
nHold[9] = j;

std::sort(nHold, nHold+9);
```

Comment: Yes CUser store ids, connection session and many other things, i just posted a small sample of it.

Comment: Why you don't like CUser as a class name haha?

Comment: @ViniciusHorta: Microsoft uses `CWhatever` in MFC, and many others copy the convention, leading to quite a few collisions.

Comment: Ah, well the source i'm studying/working in isn't mine, it was CUser before I came in hehe =P

Answer (score 2):

First brilliant idea: avoid using raw C-style arrays, they do little error checking for you...cannot be dynamically resized...and don't really help you that much in terms of performance even when you get them right.

([std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) is good, [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you feel that you must).

Second brilliant idea: employ already-written sorting algorithms, such as [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Comment: @ViniciusHorta Third brilliant idea is to take a time-out and read ["Learning Standard C++ as a New Language"](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf) by Bjarne Stroustrup.  It's accessible, very short, and one of the best captures of the "why" of C++ I've found yet.  *(In truth, suggesting you take a break to read this is perhaps the only actual unusually good idea I have to contribute here.  The rest is "obvious". :-P)*