# Program without main()?

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point

I see this interesting question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050925/is-it-possible-to-write-a-program-without-using-main-function) asking for the possibility of a program without `main()`. There, I saw [eon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481572/eon) giving one answer as follows, which works well in C/C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) m##s##u##t
#define begin decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)

int begin()
{
  printf(" hello ");
}
```

Can someone explain how the above code works? Isn't really there a `main()` here or just hiding it from our eyes archly?

Comment: Oh, please don't do that :(. That's only code obfuscation. `decode` will glue some characters together, and `begin` simply uses `decode` to glue `m` `a` `i` `n` together to `main`.

Comment: Do you know how the preprocessor works?  Specifically, the `##` operator?

Comment: Run `gcc -E` on the program to see what the preprocessor does

Comment: Why write code that is difficult to understand? Seems rather silly and a nightmare to maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't see "begin" whatsoever. It's completely substituted by the time it gets to the compiler, because macros are simply text-substitutions. Perhaps a helpful diagram to add on to the other great answers.

```
#define decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) m##s##u##t
#define begin decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)
```

Take a look at `m`, and see where `m` is in the argument list.

```
decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d)
             ^
             | 
decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)
```

Therefore the first letter is `m => m`. Then repeat the process, `s => a`, `u => i`, `t => n`.

```
decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d)
       ^ ^ ^   
       | | |
decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)
```

Then the resulting letters are "pasted" together with [token concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), and it looks like `main` as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 10):

Have a close look at the macro: it just spliced together `main` from the characters in `animate` and gets them replaced for `begin()`.

Answer (score 4):

After the macro substitution:

```
#define decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) m##s##u##t
#define begin decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)
```

`begin` becomes `decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)`, which then becomes `main`. There you have it.

Answer (score 1):

This works because the compiler doesn't really see `int begin(){}`, The preprocessor will replace `begin` with `main` after performing macro substitution and concatenation operator.

First The preprocessor will replace `begin` with `decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)`, after that it will do a rescanning on the replacement list for further replacement, it will find function-like macro `decode` which will be replaced by it's replacement list after performing the concatenation operator, like this:

```
m##a##i##n => main
```

So the compiler will only see the preprocessor output which contain `int main(){}` and not `int begin(){}` thus legal code.